# Facebook link to my redirect page opens to error 404 page on desktop but not mobile

Tags: facebook

Our company has a page on the website for a new podcast. Each episode has a unique URL. In the podcast, however, the host simplifies directing people to the relevant page by simply giving our website URL and /X (where X is the episode number).
What we've done is set up a redirect for each episode to the actual show page URL.

For instance: https://www.eliteinc.com/show/episode-1-the-power-of-day-one/

If you go to www.eliteinc.com/1 you will be taken to the correct episode page.

Here's the problem in Facebook.

When I place the www.eliteinc.com/1 link in Facebook, the preview generates just fine and if you click on the link in the post text it works.
However, if I click on the link preview that is generated, it takes me to an error 404 page:
https://www.eliteinc.com/1?fbclid=IwAR1rL41HqlLGG82vJ9bpUCV1KOKG_f3XXhEvnxk5j4vN6U0z5gJhxuOThRI

The link does open correctly on mobile.

Comment: Facebook automatically appends this `fbclid` tracking parameter to outgoing links. You need to make your site able to deal with that. If whatever rewriting you have configured currently prevents that from working, you should show us what exactly you set up for that to begin with.

Comment: The current website (WordPress) has the Duplicate Post plugin, where the Redirect From is set to (for example) /1 and the Redirect To is /show/episode-1-the-power-of-day-one

I thought adding a wildcard to the Redirect From could help, so it reads /1*

This does work, but I foresee trouble once we get to episode 10 because I assume www.eliteinc.com/10 will also be picked up by the /1*

Could a RegEx fix the issue?

Comment: Depends on what exactly this plugin matches on to apply its rewrites, whether it only checks the path component of the URL, or if it takes the query string part into account as well.